# How can I do to write "Text" just once and in the same time check if the path_info includes 'A'?

Tags: ruby, haml

```
- if !request.path_info.include? 'A'
  %{:id => 'A'}
   "Text"
- else
  "Text"
```

"Text" is written twice. How can I do to write it just once and in the same time check if the path_info includes 'A'?

Comment: Just gonna guess you like and use haml a lot? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this. Using a **partial**, or using a **content_for block**:

If "Text" was longer, or was a significant subtree, you could extract it into a partial. This would DRY up your code a little. In the example given this would seem like overkill.

The better way in this case would be to use a content_for block, like so:

```
- if !request.path_info.include? 'A'
  %{:id => 'A'}
    =yield :content
- else
  =yield :content

-content_for :content do
  Text
```

Here we yield to the content_for block in both places, removing the need to duplicate "Text". I would say in this case this is your best solution.

Comment: I should perhaps mention that this is a Rails only solution.

Comment: Yes, this only works with the Rails helpers. If you're using HAML outside of Rails, you should use Erik or Tumas' solution.

Comment: It does some interesting things within loops. To fix that you can use the index of the iteration as part of your content_for symbol. Something like: `content_for "content#{index}".to_sym`

Answer (score 2):

You can make the attribute conditional using this constuct:

```
%{:id => ('A' if request.path_info.include? 'A')}
  "Text"
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case, a division is always present with or without an id. How to also remove the div ?

Answer (score 2):

What about simply saving it inside a local variable?

```
- text = "Text"     
- if !request.path_info.include? 'A'
  %div{:id => 'A'}
    = text
- else
  = text
```

Comment: There's not much gained putting it into a variable.

Comment: You define content you want to display in one place only. Once you've done this, you can focus on the format in which you want to output it. If conditions is met, you wrap your content into inside a div, otherwise you're simply outputting it (without a div). Plus, I don't think it's possible to wrap content inside some parent tag conditionally in HAML in some one-liner because of the way it treats indentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but you can use HTML with HAML. The way I've done this is:

```
- if !request.path_info.include? 'A'
  <div id="A">
Text
- if !request.path_info.include? 'A'
  </div>
```

This is messy with such little text, but when `Text` is a large code block that you want to optionally wrap with a `div`, it can really help you follow DRY.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't. HAML is a indentation specific format, hence it can't allow you to be able to do what you want without repetition since the two conditions are separate paths while parsing.