# Is it possible to create optional parent nodes in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I love haml, but there's an issue that has always bothered me, the issue of parent nodes which may or may not be present.

In the code below I want to hyperlink some text, but only if I'm not already viewing the replies (expressed by the existence of the threaded variable in the partial). In this case I have to repeat the code that expresses the link text.

The link text code doesn't seem eligible for a helper, and it's so small it doesn't to my mind merit a partial. Is there a simple way to optionally include the parent node in this case?

```
.text
  %h2
    -if defined?(threaded)
      ="#{request.post_type.humanize}: #{request.title}"
    -else
      %a{ :href => request_path(request) }
        ="#{request.post_type.humanize}: #{request.title}"
```

Thanks in advance.

*Note:*

This question has already been answered here: [How can I do to write "Text" just once and in the same time check if the path_info includes 'A'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009443/how-can-i-do-to-write-text-just-once-and-in-the-same-time-check-if-the-path-in)

The correct answer IMO in this case is to use a content_for block.

Comment: Short answer is that you can't unfortunately. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009443/how-can-i-do-to-write-text-just-once-and-in-the-same-time-check-if-the-path-in

Comment: This question has been answered satisfactorily elsewhere. The best answer in this case was to use a content_for block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered here: [How can I do to write "Text" just once and in the same time check if the path_info includes 'A'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009443/how-can-i-do-to-write-text-just-once-and-in-the-same-time-check-if-the-path-in)

The correct answer IMO in this case is to use a content_for block.